# Meteor: sorted list

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've almost finished my meteor voting project, which based on Meteor leaderboard, but I've a little problem.

Each item in my DB has an array with the given points at the vote. I sum the array and show the result in my app. Problem: It's not sorted, it's only sorted by name (name = _id).

**HTML:**

```
<template name="voting">
    {{#each books}}
        {{> book}} 
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name="book">
    <div class="book {{selected}}">
        <span class="name">{{_id}}</span>
        <span class="totalscore">{{totalscore}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.voting.books = function () {
    return Books.find({flag: "score20130901"}, {sort: {totalscore: -1, _id: 1}});
};  

Template.book.totalscore = function () {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        total += this.score20130901[i];
    }
    return total;
};
```

**DB (example of a document)**

```
{
    _id: "Dancing Joe",
    flag: "score20130901",
    score20130714: [0,0,8,0,0],
    score20130901: [0,4,0,5,0]
}
```

Comment: Would you like to clarify a bit? For instance, the Books schema would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Benjamin. I've edited my question. My aim is to sum the score of an document and my app shows the name of all books and the totalscore in a sorted way. Hope you understand my project. It's difficult to describe, but unfortunately I can't post the whole project/sourcecode here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand. Try this ([Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is our friend here):

```
Template.voting.books = function () {
    // First, get the books as an array
    var books = Books.find({flag: "score20130901"}).fetch();
    // Next, loop through the books, using underscore's sortBy method
    return _.sortBy(books, function (book) {
        // For each book, the number it should sort by is the sum of numbers in the score array
        return _.reduce(book.score20130901, function (memo, num) {
            return memo + num;
        });
    }).reverse(); // reverse() here for descending order
};
```

Comment: It almost works, but the order of the total score is wrong. It should be descending, but it is ascending :)

Comment: Gotcha :) I've updated the answer. It's pretty simple, actually. JavaScript's got a `reverse` method for arrays

Comment: One last question Benjamin. How can I get the book with the highest score as a variable?

Comment: When it updates in the template? Instead of returning the sortBy, what if you assign that to a variable (e.g. orderedBooks), then do `Session.set('highest-book', orderedBooks[0]._id);` and then return orderedBooks? That way you have the id available as a session variable.